# Is Context.MODE_PRIVATE secure?

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to change the value for a key-value-pair created with `SharedPreferences` which uses `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`? I thought about storing the username after a successful login in SharedPreferences. Could this value be changed (e.g. with root access)?

I know that `MODE_PRIVATE` makes the file private to my application.

Comment: yes you can change the value in root access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this value be changed (e.g. with root access)?

Yes. Anything can be changed with root access.